# jQuery how to loop a function after itself?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, loops, slideshow, fadeto

I have done a ton of googling but can't seem to find the answer to this obvious question!

I have 5 images stacked on top of eachother. I am using .fadeTo(1000,0) to fadeout the 1st image in 1000ms and show the 2nd underneath. Then fade out the 2nd to show the 3rd, until it reaches the 5th. Then I .fadeIn(0,1) all the images so I can repeat this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function (){
            $('.map1').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
            $('.map2').delay(2000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
            $('.map3').delay(3000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
            $('.map4').delay(4000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
            $('.map4').fadeTo(0, 1);
            $('.map3').fadeTo(0, 1);
            $('.map2').fadeTo(0, 1);
            $('.map1').fadeTo(0, 1);
        },5000)
});
```

The problem is that the slideshow/animation doesn't correctly loop in order! It will jump from map1 to map2 and back to map1, then continue to map3..etc 
I know there is probably a better way to do this, but so far my attempts at .animate and .slideshow (plugin) have failed.

Can someone please help me order this code correctly?
I am using jQuery with Ruby on Rails (Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach that uses one loop and iterates through a list of objects on each iteration of the loop and uses animation completion functions to know when an animation is done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var items = $(".map1, .map2, .map3, .map4");
    var visibleIndex = 0;

    // establish initial opacity for only one of them visible
    items.css("opacity", 0);
    items.eq(0).css("opacity", 1);

    function next() {
        // fade out the currently visible item
        items.eq(visibleIndex).fadeTo(1000, 0);

        // at the same time, fade in the next item
        visibleIndex = ++visibleIndex % items.length;
        items.eq(visibleIndex).fadeTo(1000, 1, function() {
            // do a one second delay until the next loop is started
            setTimeout(next, 1000);
        });
    }

    // start the cycle
    next();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mLn0kznp/

The above code does a cross fade (one item fading out while another item fading in).

---

If you want one item to fade out and only when that is done will the next item start fading in (no simultaneous fading), then you can do that like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var items = $(".map");
    var visibleIndex = 0;

    // establish initial opacity for only one of them visible
    items.css("opacity", 0);
    items.eq(0).css("opacity", 1);

    function next() {
        // fade out the currently visible item
        items.eq(visibleIndex).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
            // when done fading out, fade in the next item
            visibleIndex = ++visibleIndex % items.length;
            items.eq(visibleIndex).fadeTo(1000, 1, function() {
                // do a one second delay until the next loop is started
                 setTimeout(next, 1000);
            });
        });
    }

    next();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/q26c72rz/

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a bunch! After some more jQuery practice I'm starting to understand more of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive function for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function animateMaps(i){
   if( i == $('.maps').length){
     $('.maps').fadeTo(0, 1);
   }
   else{
     $('.maps:eq('+i+')').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
         // Animation complete call function again with next index:
         animateMaps(i+1)
     });
   }
 }
  //call function 
  animateMaps(0);
});
```

```css
.maps{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  }

.blue{
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:4;
  }
.red{
  background-color:red;
  z-index:3;
  }
.green{
  background-color:green;
  z-index:2;
  }
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index:1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maps blue"></div>
<div class="maps red"></div>
<div class="maps green"></div>
<div class="maps yellow"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm studying both answers and trying to better understand how each works :)